# "Alice and Bob" problem with matrices

Tags: probability, algorithms, random

Alice has a binary matrix $A$, and Bob has a binary matrix $B$. Both matrices are of size $n \times n$.
Alice and Bob want to check if the matrices are equal except for exactly $1$ entry.
Alice has to send $\text{O}(n\log^2(n))$ message to Bob, and Bob will answer $0$ or $1$ (for "yes" or "no").

If the matrices differ in exactly $1$ entry, Bob will always return $1$ (with probability $1$).
If the matrices don't differ in exactly $1$ entry, then Bob will answer $0$ with probability of at least $50$%.

I've tried to solve this problem and after wasting hours of thinking without success I decided to try to get help here.

I'll be glad to get any clue for that one.

Comment: I think it's $O(n\log_2(n))$, right?

Comment: @the_candyman It might be, but in that case the subscript $2$ would be completely superfluous. If it's a superscript, at least it means something.

Comment: No. It's log^2.

Comment: any help? please...

Comment: Whats the question? You didn't explicitly ask us to solve anything...